# How should we deal with several now-obsolete comments from different users?

Tags: discussion, comments

I was wondering how the Aviation SE mods prefer us to deal with posts that have several now-obsolete comments from multiple users (e.g. comments that were suggesting modifications to a question that have now been made.) I know we can delete our own comments directly and can flag others as obsolete, however, in the situation described here, I wasn't sure if it was preferred for users to:

- Delete our own comments and flag each of the others as obsolete (this seems like a lot of unnecessary flags)
- Just flag one of the comments as obsolete
- Raise a custom mod flag on one of the comments stating that all of the comments are now obsolete

Sorry if this is a dupe. While it seems like this is something that has probably been covered already, I couldn't find it in a search of aviation meta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a similar meta discussion (see links below) it has been said that on the moderator side what is preferred is a custom flag on the post stating "comments need cleaning" because the interface is more friendly for them in such a scenario to perform the clean-up.

I personally reaised such a flag twice here and in both cases it was well received (it seems to me).

See also:

[Flagging obsolete comment conversations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182684/flagging-obsolete-comment-conversations)

[Right way to handle obsolete comments when some of them are mine?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259710/right-way-to-handle-obsolete-comments-when-some-of-them-are-mine)

Comment: ...it also generates fewer flag notifications than flagging each individual comment :-)